# Use micropython as interpreter in VSC (for raspberry pi pico)

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, interpreter, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I have recently gotten a raspberry pi pico and would like to use Visual Studio Code instead of Thonny to create and run my scripts that will control the components of my board. (The pico is connected to my laptop via USB)

So far i have tried using the VSC pymakr extension which is used for managing projects for the pico. I am able to get a micropython shell where i can directly write python code which will run on the pico, but can't find a way to run my currently existing scripts through VSC.

With all the online tutorials i've gone through to try and set this up i can only get as far a getting a micropython shell which also included using PuTTY. *https://www.putty.org/*

Is there a way i can easily create, edit and run scripts in VSC with micropython as my interpreter that can control my raspberry pi pico? (set my default interpreter as micropython)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pico-W-Go extension. Take a look at https://dev.to/blues/your-first-steps-with-raspberry-pi-pico-and-visual-studio-code-4jbd.  I have gotten my Micropython code to work running the current file in VSC on the Pico but have not yet been able to upload files from the PC to the Pico board. The result says the file was copied but using Thonny to check the files on the Pico board, it isn't there. Also, I haven't found a way to view the files on the Pico board from VSC like you can do in Thonny.